# I need help creating a fade in-out effect

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm creating a starfield effect and when stars stop moving, I need them to glow.

I`ve tried with TweenMax but all the elements fadeout at once.

The code that I use for creating the stars is this:

```
function createStars() {


                groupStars = new THREE.Group();
                groupStars.position.x=0;
                groupStars.position.y=0;
                groupStars.position.z=0;

                var materialList = [];
                var boxGeo = new THREE.CircleGeometry(1, 50);
                for ( var i = 0; i < 1000; i ++ ) {
                    materialList.push (new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                        color: new THREE.Color(0xFFFFFF),
                        specular: new THREE.Color(0xFFFFFF),
                        shininess: 10,
                        flatShading: THREE.FlatShading,
                        transparent: 1,
                        opacity: 1,
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide
                    }));
                    box = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeo, materialList[i]);
                    box.position.x = Math.random() * 1400 - 500;
                    box.position.y = Math.random() * 1400 - 1000;
                    box.position.z = Math.random();

                    groupStars.add( box );
                    stars.push(box);
                }

                scene.add( groupStars );
            }
```

When the stars are created, I call this function for the animation:

```
function animateStars() {

  for(var i=0; i<stars.length; i++) {
    star = stars[i];
    var randomItem = stars[Math.floor(Math.random()*stars.length)];
    starWidth = star.scale.x;
    starHeight = star.scale.y;
    var k = 50;
    if( speed == false ) {
        star.position.z +=  i/20;
    } else {
        TweenMax.to(randomItem.scale, 2, {x: i*0.005, y: i*0.005, z: i*0.005, yoyo: true, repeat: -1});
    }

    if(star.position.z>1000){
        star.position.z-=2000;
    }

  }

}
```

By using this:

```
TweenMax.to(randomItem.scale, 2, {x: i*0.005, y: i*0.005, z: i*0.005, yoyo: true, repeat: -1});
```

I've managed to get some effect on the elements, but not quite what I'm looking for

I'm trying to get something like this:
https://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/index.html

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Thanks to the example posted by [prisoner849](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4045502/prisoner849) I managed to make it work adding this to the animateStars() function, I don't know if this is the cleanest way to to this, but I'm really new at this:

```
function animateStars() {

                var time = Date.now() * 0.005;

                for(var i=0; i<stars.length; i++) {

                    star = stars[i];
                    var randomItem = stars[Math.floor(Math.random()*stars.length)];
                    starWidth = star.scale.x;
                    starHeight = star.scale.y;
                    var k = 50;
                    if( speed == false ) {
                        star.position.z +=  i/20;
                    } else {

                        star.scale.y = 0.6 * ( 1 + Math.sin( 0.6 * i - time ) );
                        star.scale.x = 0.6 * ( 1 + Math.sin( 0.6 * i - time ) );

                    }

                    if(star.position.z>1000){
                        star.position.z-=2000;
                    }

                }

            }
```

Comment: What exactly isn't as expected? You are looping through the stars, and picking one at random, this means that the same star may be picked more than once and it probably wont end up picking them all. I am not sure if you are wanting to animate them all, or just some, but you probably have to rethink the randomizing part.

Comment: Have a look at this [official example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=attr#webgl_buffergeometry_custom_attributes_particles)

Comment: Thanks prisoner849, the example helped a lot.

Comment: @user2324366 You're welcome :)